# How can I avoid a segmentation fault while resize a vector like this

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I think it is a simple question for you....i am pretty new in c++.....

So i have a vector defined like this:

`vector<vector<float> > big_vector;`

I read a file and initialized this vector, then the big_wector has about 200,000 elements in it. each is a vector < float >

Then I wanted to modify the elements in big_vector, for some elements I need to resize them first,(e.g. from 0 to 300)

`big_vector[i].resize(new_size);`

When I ran the program, first it went well, after some modifications, a "segmentation fault" occurred at the line above.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to examine the values you are passing to see if they are out of range?

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. If you posted the code we could at least see what you are doing. An English description of the problem is NOT a good idea as this explains what you think you are doing not what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to resize big_vector, so that it has some vectors to resize.

```
int total_vectors = 100;
big_vector.resize(total_vectors);
for(int i = 0; i < total_vectors; ++i)
     big_vector[i].resize(new_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to resize vectors? Are simple push_back is not enough? Or do you set some values by index?

If you set values by index I'd recommend to use std::generate_n with std::back_inserter

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of vectors.

Before you can access `big_vector[i]` (the vector of floats at i) you must set the size of big_vector itself.